# Wix check if file exists?

Tags: wix

I'm trying to see if a file exists with Wix. I have tried the following:

```
<Property Id="TEMPFILE" >
  <DirectorySearch Path="[TempFolder]" Depth="0" Id="TempFolderDirectorySearcher">
    <FileSearch Name="temp.txt"/>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

But it seems this property is initialized on startup then never again. I am creating the file during a deferred custom action. What would be the best way to check if this propery exists after that action? (Or force the property to re-populate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using a custom action. VBScript code is similar to this:

```
'Set Dimension
DIM fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Set our targetFile
DIM targetFile
targetFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
targetFile= tempFile & "\temp.txt"

' Check to see if our file exists
If ( fso.FileExists( tempFile ) ) Then
    Session.Property("TempFileExists") = "TRUE"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

DirectorySearch is performed by AppSearch which runs fairly early during the install.  Also deferred custom actions can't set properties so I'm not sure how it could be possible to accomplish what you are trying to do.  I think you need to examine what you are really trying to do and then redesign it to fit the way Windows Installer works.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to install something else depending on whether this very file is installed or not, you'd better put the same condition to component(s) containing that "something". Also, consider separating the related stuff into the features.